# Appium cannot find input field elements in android native app by id

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I am very fresh in appium and just facing the problem that I cannot write in the input fields because appium cannot find them by IDs. Googling around did not bring some working solutions and I hope that someone has some interesting solution.

Comment: How you get the IDs of input fields?

Comment: Trying to find a web element "by ID" in Appium is NOT the same as doing it in Selenium if you are using xpath.  If you are using MobileElement/AndroidElement and it's a native app, then by.ID will work, provided to use the full ID as shown in UIAutomator, but a common mistake when using xpath is referring to 'id' when it should be 'resource-id'

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Make sure you're waiting for element to be visible before interacting with it.

**2.** If you have some webViews in your app, you *might* need to change the context. e.g.:

```
// Get all contexts
Set<String> contexts = driver.getContextHandles();

// Get current context
String current = driver.getContext();

// Use context  
driver.context("context");
```

**3.** Then you can use 
     `driver.findElementById("your_element_id");`